# Adding button to a jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am having a table in which i have to adda JButton.

I am doing

```
TableColumnModel colModel = table.getColumnModel();
    colModel.getColumn(0).setCellEditor(new MYCellEditor(new JCheckbox()));

MyCellEditor extends DefaultCellEditor{

public MyCellEditor(JCheckbox checkbox){

  super(checkbox);
 Jbutton button = new JButton("Start");
 //actionlistener for button.
 }

 }
 MyRenderer extends DefaultTablecellRenderer{

   public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    //return a button for column ==0     
  }
```

My understanding is that the Celleditor has same instance of button for all cells in a column. So if i click on one button the text changes from "Start" to "stop" but if i click on button in other row it doesnt work.. After debugging it shows that the text is alreadt Stop .

How can i have different instance of button in each row ?

Comment: I gave you a working answer on this topic 2 weeks ago. You didn't bother to accept the answer then (or any other answer given), so I won't waste my time repeating the answer again.

Comment: @camickr - the url doesnt open in the office because of privacy issue. But this time i went home and saw the solution . it really helped . thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article [*Table Button Column*](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) cited in @camickr's previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249219) provides a more flexible solution, but you may find the tutorial [*How to Use Tables: Using Other Editors*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editor) helpful, too. The [`ColorEditor`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableDialogEditDemoProject/src/components/ColorEditor.java) discussed there is part of the [`TableDialogEditDemo`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/index.html#TableDialogEditDemo), available via [Java Web Start](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17746_01/tutorialJWS/uiswing/components/ex6//TableDialogEditDemo.jnlp). You'll need to change the corresponding [`ColorRenderer`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableDialogEditDemoProject/src/components/ColorRenderer.java) accordingly.